# Styling multiple subgrids in jqGrid so they are horizontally aligned.

Tags: javascript, css, jqgrid

Hi I've been trying to figure out if its even possible to take a jqGrid with 3 subgrids and align them so they are horizontally aligned. Like this:

================================================== 
|***_*___**| |**__*_*__**| |**__*_*__*_*____**|

I've tried setting each one to float left/right ect... but the style gets overwritten even when set to important. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
subGridRowExpanded: function(subGridDivId,rowId){
        $("#ClassGroupGrid").jqGrid('setSelection',rowId);
        var subgridClassTableId = subGridDivId + "_class_t";
        var subgridCreationTableID = subGridDivId + '_creation_t';
        var subgridConnectionTableID = subGridDivId + '_connection_t';

        $("#" + subGridDivId).html("<table style='float: left !important' id='" +      subgridClassTableId + "'></table>");
        $("#" + subgridClassTableId).jqGrid({
            datatype: 'local',
            data: classGroupData[parseInt(rowId) -1],
            colNames:['Classes'],
            colModel:[
                {name:'Classes', formatter: classGroupClassesFormatter}
            ],
            shrinkToFit: true
        });

        $('#' + subGridDivId).append("<table id='" + subgridCreationTableID + "'></table>");
        $("#" + subgridCreationTableID).jqGrid({
            datatype: 'local',
            data: classGroupData[parseInt(rowId) -1],
            colNames:['Creation Rules'],
            colModel:[
                {name:'Creation Rules', formatter: classGroupCreationFormatter}
            ],
            shrinkToFit: true
        });

        $('#' + subGridDivId).append("<table style='float: right !important' id='" + subgridConnectionTableID + "'></table>");
        $("#" + subgridConnectionTableID).jqGrid({
            datatype: 'local',
            data: classGroupData[parseInt(rowId) -1],
            colNames:['Connection Rules'],
            colModel:[
                {name:'Connection Rules', formatter: classGroupConnectionFormatter}
            ],
            shrinkToFit: true
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why did I see... "Slaying multiple subgrids" instead?

Comment: wouldnt mind slaying these subgrids honestly, been trying to get a decent way to display multiple arrays of different sizes in them

Comment: Would it be possible to set up a jsFiddle for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Brilliand idea was close and led me to the answer. The structure of the subgrids is this:

```
<td role='row' class='ui-subgrid'>
<td role='row' class='ui-widget-content subgrid-cell'>
    <div class=tablediv>
        //divs containing subgrids
```

After trying a couple of them i was finally able to find the correct parent as the 'ui-subgrid'. IF you float this left and then float each of your sub grids left you will get the answer you wanted except for little caveat. You need to set your width of 'ui-subgrid' to be able to contain all of the subgrids. So the css to do this is (at least how i set it up):

```
.ui-subgrid{
float:left !important;
width: 1000px !important;
}
```

Then in your subgridrowexpanded function:

```
$('#gbox_' + subgridClassTableId).css("float", "left");
```

subgridclasstableid being whatever your unique id for each subgrid being.

Comment: If you don't want the grids to be able to word-wrap, a better solution (for browsers that support it - everything but IE6&7) is to use `display: table-cell;`.  That way, setting the width on `ui-subgrid` won't be necessary.  (You can enhance things a bit more by using `display: table; width: 100%;` on the parent node of those divs.)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that jqGrid is putting each table inside its own `div`.  If that's the case, then putting `float: left` on the table won't make much difference; you have to put it on the containing div.  Try this:

```
$("#" + subGridDivId).css("float", "left");
```

Without looking at the generated HTML, however, I can't know for sure whether that's the right element.  The 'golden rule' is that the elements that you float left should all be siblings of each other in the HTML.

Comment: You were close, and your idea led me to get the right answer. They wrapped the different sub grids a couple times.